# MonoTouch equivalent of transform.b and transform.a?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, transform, cgaffinetransform

iOS has a property on a transform of "b" and "a".  Example iOS code is below.  What is the mono / monotouch equivalent?

```
CGFloat radians = atan2f(container.transform.b, container.transform.a);
```

Answer (score 4):

Apple's [`CGAffineTransform`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html) is defined with letters: a, b, c, d for it's matrix member (except the translation part).

```
struct CGAffineTransform {
    CGFloat a;
    CGFloat b;
    CGFloat c;
    CGFloat d;
    CGFloat tx;
    CGFloat ty;
};
```

Meanwhile MonoTouch use the, more .NET-like (e.g. System.Drawing), naming of: xx, yx, xy, yy.

```
public struct CGAffineTransform {
   public float xx;   // a
   public float yx;   // b 
   public float xy;   // c
   public float yy;   // d
   public float x0;   // tx
   public float y0;   // ty
}
```

That makes it easier to port existing C# code.